# Facing error Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not register on local machine

Tags: c#, excel, console-application

I work on `Windows 7` (64 bit), `Visual Studio 2010` and `Microsoft Office` (32 bit).
I got error that:

> Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0 provider is not register on local machine.

I got this error when I am trying to open connection for `Excel` file in console Application. I tried to put my build in the `Configuration Manager` dialog box as "x86", but problem still occurs.

Also I am no able to download any type of software or like `AccessDatabaseEngine`, because its client machine.

Can Anyone help me to sort out problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got solution. I tried all available solution, there is problem with administration rights. also not properly installed visual studion.